# Calling a bash script from a tcl script and returning and exit status

Tags: bash, tcl

I am attempting to call a bash script from a TCL script and need to get exit status from the bash script or at least pass something back into the TCL script so that I can tell if my script executed successfully. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking how to trap a return value in TCL, or how to return an exit status from bash.

Comment: @Simon Hibbs: Ideally I would like to capture the exit status from my bash script in tclsh.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See http://wiki.tcl.tk/exec -- click the "Show discussion" button -- there's a very detailed example of how to do exactly what you're asking. What you need though is `catch`

```
set status [catch {exec script.bash} output]

if {$status == 0} {
    puts "script exited normally (exit status 0) and wrote nothing to stderr"
} elseif {$::errorCode eq "NONE"} {
    puts "script exited normally (exit status 0) but wrote something to stderr which is in $output"
} elseif {[lindex $::errorCode 0] eq "CHILDSTATUS"} {
    puts "script exited with status [lindex $::errorCode end]."
} else ...
```

Comment: The definitive link is an example from the Tcl 8.6 documentation: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm#M29

Comment: nice. the Tcl 8.5 docs have the same examples: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm#M28

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [exec](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1039) the result of which will be in the return value, be warned however there are lots of gotchas using exec, particularly if you need to do any complex quoting

Comment: That is what I thought but didn't seem to getting anything when I tried to grab the result of my exec. I would try something like this: set value [exec bash script.sh] and value wouldn't contain anything regardless of what the scripts exit status was?

Answer (score 1):

My experience in tcl is limited to occasional dabbling.  However, following links starting with the one in @jk's answer led me to [this page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8489) which discusses the errorCode variable and related things that might be useful this circumstance.  Here's a quick example demonstrating the use of errorCode:

tcl:

```
set ret_val [catch { exec /bin/bash /path/to/bash_script }]
set errc $errorCode
set ret_val [lindex [split $errc " " ] 2]
puts $ret_val
```

bash_script, as referenced above:

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 42
```

which led to output of:

> 42